# Slide not working under https

Tags: html, css, https

So I have this slideshow in the homepage that shows five slides. It works ok, but not under https

Firefox loads great with no issues under https but not chrome nor IE9/10

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once possible problem is that there might be some syntax error in your webpage. Try running it through software like visual studio to dreamweaver to look for errors. Certain web browser can be forgiving but this is not the case for most browsers.